# Can the Observer Pattern be removed from MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, class-diagram

I want to know if you can remove the Observer Pattern from MVC (where the Observer goes from the Model to the View, notifying any changes in the Model and updating the View), and what would be the consequences if we remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you would "remove" it, but if you simply don't use it, then the consequences would be that your controller would be responsible for updating the views with changes from the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove it (depending on the framework you're using) but you'll need to be wary of situations where you're displaying the same data in multiple locations as they will become out of sync. I can't see that it would cause any issues design wise or theory wise, but it may be confusing to the user in some circumstances.